# input в ссылку не передает остаток url?text=мой текст

Tags: javascript

Код ниже работает. Но как добавить продолжение ссылки, например, такой  ?text=мой текст

```
<form name="idform">
    <input type="tel" name="id" placeholder="номер с кодом страны">
    <input type="button" value="Отправить" 
           onclick="location.href='https://wa.me/'+escape(document.forms['idform'].elements['id'].value)">
</form>
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="?text=Мой текст">  Как добавить значение невидимого input как продолжение ссылки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо просто немного дополнить формируемую строку:

```
<form name="idform">
    <input type="tel" name="id" placeholder="номер с кодом страны">
    <input type="hidden" id="vizHid" name="vizitka" value="?text=$link">
    <input type="button" value="Отправить"
           onclick="location.href='https://example.com/'+escape(document.forms['idform'].elements['id'].value)+document.forms['idform'].elements['vizHid'].value">
</form>
```

Comment: @JandosM А `?text=$link` где лежит? Покажите полный пример

Comment: Номер телефона вводится в поле, а $link берется из БД

Comment: @JandosM Обновил ответ

Comment: Работает. Спасибо!